# PHP MySQL library differs from your MySQL server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-14.04

I get that error on phpMyAdmin

```
"Your PHP MySQL library version 5.5.43 differs from your MySQL 
server version 5.6.19. This may cause unpredictable behavior."
```

On many forums I saw I had to reinstall it with apptitude, but I made a manual install, so I really don't know how to fix this.

I also compiled PHP, so maybe something is missing:

`ubuntu 14.04.2, php 5.6.9, apache 2.4.7, mysql 5.6.19`

Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alone. Ubuntu, PHP and Apache cannot communicate with MySQL. You need to find the correct driver and manually tell PHP where it is and to load it. The downloads can be found here;

http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-php/

Then you must edit your php.ini file and add/uncomment a dynamic extension directive;

```
extension=modulename.extension
```

Though, this driver is no longer supported for more information see;

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqlinfo.api.choosing.html

Comment: the link is only for windows... and it says connectors dev is discontinued 
strange I never had to worry about this before, justall mysql and that's it
but I wanted to have the latest version of php

Comment: Indeed, sorry about that. I never noticed. I'm not aware if yum/apt supports versions.

Comment: but it does not make sens, If you check http://www.virgohacks.net/install-apache-2-4-mysql-5-6-php-5-5-source-ubuntu-14-04/, they install ubuntu 2.4, mysql 5.6.19 and php 5.5, they dont seem to have any issue

actually, only phpmyadmin complains about that

Comment: Its a reasonable assumption that if the driver you are using wasn't built for the version of MySql your using then there could be a compatibility issue, this is what the message from phpMyAdmin is telling you. No one is saying categorically that a problem exists. You can however look for evidence or give prove you've found a compatibility issue yourself. Either find a matching driver or don't, it's entirely your choice, using a matching driver will fix the error though.

Comment: ok but how do I find that version of mysql driver for php, I keep digging the web with no luck.. http://community.rtcamp.com/t/phpmyadmin-broken-version-issue/3683/2

Comment: You probably wont. MySql doesn't support the driver anymore and they have released replacement, better and faster drivers. If you absolutely have to use that specific driver use an older version of MySql, or accept there may be a problem down the line and be forced to downgrade MySql or update your code.